# Quick question about restarting levels on fail

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a quick question for you. I have already everything prepared. I am making a simple launching game, where you need to kill all enemies (not time-based) to pass to the next level. I have 2 methods GoToNextLevel() and AllMonsterDied(); .

Need to make something like player have 3 attempts (3 launchings whenever he wants not based on time).
Then every launch checks if any monster left. If does just show 1 attemps less. After 3 times just restart scene.

Thanks a lot since I am new to both c# and unity that would mean the world to me.

```
public class LevelController: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] string _nextLevelName;
         
    Monster[] _monsters;
 
    void OnEnable()
    {
        _monsters = FindObjectsOfType<Monster>();
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
        int currentLevel = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
 
        if (currentLevel >= PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelsUnlocked"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("levelsUnlocked", currentLevel + 1);
        }
 
        if (MonsterAreAllDead() )
        {
            GoToNextLevel();
        }
        
        Debug.Log("Level" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelsUnlocked") + "UNLOCKED");
    }
 
    void GoToNextLevel()
    {
        Debug.Log("Go to next level" + _nextLevelName);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(_nextLevelName);
    }
    
    bool MonsterAreAllDead()
    {
        foreach (var monster in _monsters)
        {
            if (monster.gameObject.activeSelf)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Line from Monster.cs

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)  
    {
        if (SouldDieFromCollision(collision))
        {
            tickSource.Play();
             StartCoroutine(Die());
        }
    }

IEnumerator Die()
    {
        _hasDied =true;
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite=_deadsprite;
        _particleSystem.Play(); 
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);


        gameObject.SetActive(false);

    }
```

Comment: so what exactly have you tried and what exactly isn't behaving as expected? Wouldn't it be enough to change the player settings, **once** in `GoToNextLevel` ? Also you should think more event based and not poll check your monsters every frame in `Update` ...

Comment: @derHugo Thanks alot for your reply. I tried something with If statement like (! allMonestersDied) { restart level }   but I m not sure how it works If i want to make 3 chance or smething

Comment: And how would your current code know, when one attempt finished?

Comment: @derHugo Hmm do you maybe want me to post my monster script? I though something like adding variable and add it to code maybe check 3 times if monsters still alive (one per launch) and if not go to next scene if yes restart level (scene) but not that active, insted go  to previous scene like -1

Comment: again: How exactly will you determine at which moment exactly one "launch" is finished? You don't want to do the check all the time but only in the moment where you say the launch is done .. e.g. because nothing is moving anymore or something similar

Comment: @derHugo ah I wil update my question with line of my code in my monster script.

Comment: @derHugo I added, maybe after respawn ?

Comment: It doesn't look like from your `Monster` class you can determine if one attempt is finished .. you only know if this specific monster was killed ... that doesn't seem to be enough information to know when your current attempt is over ...

Comment: @derHugo Hmm, can you maybe help me to make some method that after every coroutine counts like an attempt?

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you want the next level launch attempt happen when the player hits `N` key on the keyboard.
When the player hits the key, check if all monsters are dead. If so, call `GoToNextLeve()`, otherwise take off 1 attempt from the attempts available and restart the current scene.

```
int attempts;

void OnEnable()
{
    attempts = 3;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.H)
    {
        TryGoToNextLevel();
    }
}

void TryGoToNextLevel()
{
    if (MonsterAreAllDead() )
    {
        GoToNextLevel();
    }
    else
    {
        attempts--;
    }
    if (attempts <= 0)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(
            SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```